# UIView animation happening immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have an animation of three buttons that used to work properly until I added different possible positions for the buttons. Now the animation happens immediately, but I'm not sure why.

Here's some code:

```
defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
_btnCuenta3.hidden=NO;
CGPoint newPosition2;
CGPoint newPosition3;
CGPoint newPositionAgregar;
if([defaults objectForKey:@"cuenta3"]){
    newPosition2=CGPointMake(200.0f + _btnCuenta2.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta2.center.y);
    newPosition3=CGPointMake(165.0f + _btnCuenta3.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta3.center.y);
    newPositionAgregar=CGPointMake(130.0f + _btnAgregar.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnAgregar.center.y);
    _btnCuenta2.center=newPosition2;
    _btnCuenta3.center=newPosition3;
    _btnAgregar.center=newPositionAgregar;
}else if([defaults objectForKey:@"cuenta2"]){
    newPosition2=CGPointMake(200.0f + _btnCuenta2.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta2.center.y);
    newPositionAgregar=CGPointMake(165.0f + _btnAgregar.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnAgregar.center.y);
    _btnCuenta2.center=newPosition2;
    _btnAgregar.center=newPositionAgregar;
}else{
    newPositionAgregar=CGPointMake(200.0f + _btnAgregar.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnAgregar.center.y);
    _btnAgregar.center=newPositionAgregar;
}
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Any idea why it's happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: move the `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` and `[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];` to before the `if`.

Comment: The `[UIView begin/commitAnimations]` methods are obsolete. Use the newer block versions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` should be first line before doing any changes to uiview contents.

**Code:**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];

//View changes code

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not animating anything. You are simply changing the property which happens instantly. Do something like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        if([defaults objectForKey:@"cuenta3"]){
    newPosition2=CGPointMake(200.0f + _btnCuenta2.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta2.center.y);
    newPosition3=CGPointMake(165.0f + _btnCuenta3.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta3.center.y);
    newPositionAgregar=CGPointMake(130.0f + _btnAgregar.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnAgregar.center.y);
    _btnCuenta2.center=newPosition2;
    _btnCuenta3.center=newPosition3;
    _btnAgregar.center=newPositionAgregar;
}else if([defaults objectForKey:@"cuenta2"]){
    newPosition2=CGPointMake(200.0f + _btnCuenta2.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnCuenta2.center.y);
    newPositionAgregar=CGPointMake(165.0f + _btnAgregar.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnAgregar.center.y);
    _btnCuenta2.center=newPosition2;
    _btnAgregar.center=newPositionAgregar;
}else{
    newPositionAgregar=CGPointMake(200.0f + _btnAgregar.frame.size.width/2.0f, _btnAgregar.center.y);
    _btnAgregar.center=newPositionAgregar;
}

}];
```

Comment: These newer block animations are the preferred approach. The old methods are obsolete.